# Нужен алгоритм сравнения кастомных объектов

Tags: java, c#, python, c, алгоритм

Понадобилось сделать сравнение. Есть 2 листа объектов одного типа (`field1` и `field2` в примере). У объекта есть 3 строковых параметра (имя, фамилия, отчество). В первом объекте есть записи о 3-х людях со всеми заполненными полями, т.е. он выглядит примерно так:

1. Имя        Фамилия      Отчество
2. Юрий       Карамазин     Александрович
3. Виктор      Сушко         Григорьевич
4. Саша        Князев        Альбертович

И второй объект, в котором записи о тех же 3-х людях, но хранятся только имена:

1. Имя
2. Юрий
3. Виктор
4. Саша

Мне необходимо сравнивать только параметр объекта "имя". Пытаюсь сравнивать как-то так:

```
for (FieldOfTest x : field1) {
    for (FieldOfTest y : field2) {
        Assert.assertTrue(x.getName().equals(y.getName()),
                "First value: " + x.getName() + " , second value: " + y.getName());
    }
}
```

Второй `for` прокручивает полный список. Как мне сравнивать 1 объект из первого списка с одним объектом второго списка?

Comment: А какова конечная цель всего этого сравнения? И если нужно сравнивать первый элемент `field1` только с первым элементом `field2`, второй - только со вторым и т.д., то это делается одним циклом.

Comment: это тест. Просто первый объект формируется выборкой из базы абсолютно всей информации, следовательно объекты получаются полными, а второй парсится с сайта где представлены только имена. Т.е. по сути мне надо удостоверится, что список имён, которые я спарсил с сайта, соответствует списку имён из базы. И да, по сути, вы правильно указали, необходимо сравнивать только поле "имя" первого объекта в листе1 с полем "имя" первого объекта в листе2; поле "имя" второго объекта в листе1 с полем "имя" второго объекта в листе2, и т.д. до конца листа. Может это реально можно упростить ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если сравнивать нужно только элементы, находящиеся на одинаковых индексах, то достаточно использовать один `for`, предварительно убедившись, что массивы равной длины:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<FieldOfTest> field1 = new ArrayList<>();
    field1.add(new FieldOfTest("Юрий", "Карамазин Александрович"));
    field1.add(new FieldOfTest("Виктор", "Сушко Григорьевич"));
    field1.add(new FieldOfTest("Саша", "Князев Альбертович"));
    List<FieldOfTest> field2 = new ArrayList<>();
    field2.add(new FieldOfTest("Юрий", null));
    field2.add(new FieldOfTest("Виктор", null));
    field2.add(new FieldOfTest("Саша", null));
    System.out.println("Data is correct: " + isCorrectData(field1, field2));
}

private static boolean isCorrectData(List<FieldOfTest> field1, List<FieldOfTest> field2)
{
    if (field1.size() != field2.size())
    {
        return false;
    }
    boolean isCorrect = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < field1.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!field1.get(i).getName().equals(field2.get(i).getName()))
        {
            isCorrect = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isCorrect;
}
```

Реализация на Java.

Comment: вот это очень похоже на то, что надо. Но, подскажите как можно обойти то, что у меня аргументы isCorrectData - (ArrayList<FieldOfTest> field1, ArrayList<FieldOfTest> field2). Я вот не совсем понимаю. Это же листы объектов, а java мне пишет, что я не могу взять length, почему (я так понимаю раз пишет, что есть size - то это объект, а не итерабельная сущность типа листа)?  

Java предложила переделать внутренний if в такую конструкцию:
if (!field1.get(i).getName().equals(field2.get(i).getName())) {
                isCorrect = false;
                break;
            }

Comment: но как быть с первоначальной проверкой длин ? или мне надо это всё запихнуть в общий for, и там уже делать проверки, создать лист boolean, вставлять туда результат каждой итерации и потом проверять нет ли в этом списке false-ов ?

Comment: @Ustin пардон, я забыл, что у вас `List`-ы, а не массивы. Сейчас подкорректирую код.

Comment: @Ustin в `List` вместо `.length` есть метод `.size()`, который возвращает количество элементов в этом списке. И получение элементов происходит через метод `.get(int index)`, как вам правильно подсказала среда разработки. Код изменил.

Comment: @Ustin если списки (`List`) разной длины, то имеет смысл сразу возвращать `false`, ибо имена в них полностью совпасть определённо уже не смогут. Заводить целый список булевых значений смысла нет: вам ведь нужно просто узнать, все ли имена в списках совпадают, а для этого достаточно ответа "да/нет".

Comment: вот тут вопрос, как определяется size. Это просто количество моих объектов в листе ? или учитыватется размер (т.е. например будут ли равны через size два листа, если в первом 10 объектов, с полной информацией(имя, фамилия, отчество), а во втором 10 объектов с именами)?

Comment: @Ustin да, просто количество объектов в списке. Поэтому значения внутри объектов никак не влияют на возвращаемое методом `size()` значение.

Answer (score 5):

Ну как то так наверное:

```
HashMap hashFields=new HashMap<String, FieldOfTest>();
for(FieldOfTest x:field1)
   hashFields.put(x.getName(), x);

//теперь находим в первом списке по именам со второго списка
for(FieldOfTest y:field2)  //y содержит только имена
   if(hashFields.get(y)!=null)
      //bingo!
```

P.S. @VladD опередил.

P.P.S. код для Java

Answer (score 4):

Вам в любом случае нужно искать по всему контейнеру. Но я бы перешёл к структуре данных с более эффективным поиском. Например, положил бы имена в `HashSet<string>` или аналогичную структуру данных в вашем языке, с поиском O(1).

Comment: Ну просто это упрощённая модель, там в объекте на самом деле ещё много полей с разными типами. Я упростил, чтобы проще понять суть. Я в данной реализации с листами не выйдет это сделать ? Просто если листы объектов я видел, и хоть как-то знаю, то hashset - это для меня вообще фантастика.

Comment: @Ustin: Лист — это линейный список? Нет, они по сути ничем не отличаются от массивов, только умеют расти. HashSet не фантастика, он есть в стандартной библиотеке большинства языков, так что это должно быть просто.

Comment: @Ustin: А если там более сложный объект, поместите его в `Dictionary<string, ВашОбъект>`, поиск по ключу тоже O(1).

Answer (score 2):

> необходимо сравнивать только поле "имя" первого объекта в листе1 с полем "имя" первого объекта в листе2; поле "имя" второго объекта в листе1 с полем "имя" второго объекта в листе2, и т.д. до конца листа

В Питоне:

```py
all(a.name == b.name for a, b in zip(list1, list2))
```

Полный пример:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name lastname patronymic')

list1 = [Person(*s.split()) for s in """\
Юрий Карамазин Александрович
Виктор Сушко Григорьевич
Саша Князев Альбертович""".split('\n')]

list2 = [Person(name, None, None) for name in """
Юрий
Виктор
Саша""".split()]

if all(a.name == b.name for a, b in zip(list1, list2)):
    print('equal')
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант для `java`. Сложность `O(n)`

```
private static class A {
    String name;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof A)) return false;
        A a = (A) o;
        return name.equals(a.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }
}

private static class B extends A {
    String surname;
    String middleName;
}

private static boolean isEquals(List<A> firstList, List<B> secondList) {
    if (firstList.size() != secondList.size())
        return false;

    Set<A> buffer = new HashSet<>(secondList);
    for (A obj : firstList)
        if (!buffer.contains(obj))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```